# How to save text entered in UITextField contained in a UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

In my app I am dynamically creating a table view cell with 2 controls one is`UILabel` to display title which i am receiving from a web service and other is a`UITextField`. This `UITextField` will take user input.

Now all field names and field types are received from web service, so i don't know which field will come every time?

So, When user enter corresponding values to fields how can i save them and identify them to which title they belong??

I tried [this](http://windrealm.org/tutorials/uitableview_uitextfield_form.php) option but its only for static`UITableView` (they already know which fields are belonging to values)

I will get an array of fields like 'height','blood pressure',..etc.
My UI is something like this

[image]

and in my Code part

```
.m file is 

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;    //count of section
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return [fieldName count]; //dynamic field name array count

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"cell";

    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[testCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                             reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    }

    NSString *uppercaseString = [[fieldName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] uppercaseString];
    cell.title.text=uppercaseString;//filed name

    return cell;
}
```

From this how do i get input text values and save it???

Comment: Do you want to save value on any action or click??

Comment: Use datasource to save values.

Comment: yes, when i click button i need to save values

Comment: As iphonic said, you have a dataSource.  Use it!

Comment: Where is your UITextField and Save Button in your code or design ???

Comment: "Reading" is a UITextField and at bottom there is continue button

Comment: @abhibangalore your problem is solved or not.

Comment: @abhibangalore please reply your problem is solve or not. and if solve then accept any one answer which you think more correct. and helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use [FXForms](https://github.com/nicklockwood/FXForms), which is designed for dynamic tableview. It saves and fetches form model data using key-value coding pattern.

Answer (score 0):

If getting the values from the form fields and storing them is your issue, try this approach. I am still not sure what exactly you are looking for.

**Add your form field objects to a NSMutableArray. When the done button is clicked, iterate through the array and get the corresponding field objects and the user entered values from it.**

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
return 1;    //count of section
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

return [fieldName count]; //dynamic field name array count

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
     cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"cell";

     if (!self.fieldsArray) {
        self.fieldsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
     }       

    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[CustomCell alloc]init]
    }

    NSString *uppercaseString = [[fieldName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] uppercaseString];

    cell.titleLabel.text=uppercaseString;//filed name


     UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 30, 250, 250)];
     [cell.contentView addSubview:textField];
     [self.fieldsArray addObject:textField];    

    }

    return cell;
}

//Button Click
-(IBAction)doneSelection:(id)sender{
    for (id *field in _testArray) {
        if ([field isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
             NSString* userEnteredValue = field.text;
        }else if ([field isKindOfClass:[UISlider class]]){
           //Handle for other types
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: my question is very clear and please don't post these kind of answers, its totally meaningless

Comment: Regret that it is annoying  you. I just tried to help. nothing else is intended.

Comment: You are not understanding exact problem.....dynamic means no hard coding first of all !! but still you hard coded "height" !!!

Comment: @Abhi, that is just a sample code. Please have a look at the concept. You can have your own implementation based on your needs. Please modify my code and check. Please don't expect the complete code to be shared.

Comment: @abhibangalore how about being a decent human being and not shouting at everyone who's trying to help?

Answer (score 0):

You can tag each label and textfield with same value, suppose row1 will have tag value 1 and row2 will have both label and textfield will have tag value 2, thus you can identify the pair easily and get the text. Modify your method like this

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
     cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"cell";
cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[testCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
}
UILabel *lblTilte=[[UILabel alloc]init];
[lblTilte setFrame:<#(CGRect)#>];//set your own frame
NSString *uppercaseString = [[fieldName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] uppercaseString];
[lblTilte setText:uppercaseString];//your title received from web service
lblTilte.tag=indexPath.row;//identify pair
[cell.contentView addSubview:lblTilte];

UITextField *inputTextField=[[UITextField alloc]init];
[inputTextField setFrame:<#(CGRect)#>];//set your own frame
inputTextField.tag=indexPath.row;//identify pair
[cell.contentView addSubview:inputTextField];
return cell;}
```

Now when you receive input match it with tag. you can get input values in text field delegate methods , textfield did end editing or if you have cell selection method, there also you can retrieve the values.

Answer (score -2):

To save Data locally you can use .Plist(Property List).

Create  `NSMutableArray` and reload `UITableView` in`viewWillAppear` Method.

.Plist is best way to store data or save data.
Or 
you can also use the core data for it.

Or if you have very small amount of data then you can use NSUserDefaults.

Comment: Please try above answer. it will solve your problem.